Picamera2 installation issues in Raspberry Pi 5
Does anybody know how can I install Picamera2 on Raspberry Pi 5 (Ubuntu 23.10)?
I've two Noir V3 Camera modulus, and I want to use Python code for my image processing work by open cv and qt5 (like this way: https://github.com/JungLearnBot/RPi5_yolov8/blob/main/main_picam.py).
I tried sudo apt install python3-libcamera, and installed without error. but sudo apt install python3-picamera2 doesn't work and says: unable to locate package python3-pycamera2.

You can use pip https://pypi.org/project/picamera2/

When I use 'sudo apt install -y python3-libcamera python3-kms++' receive the same error: 'Unable to locate package python3-kms+'

You don't need to use apt to install Python packages
